# remove blank space in group crystal report

Tags: visual-studio, crystal-reports

[this is my report look like](https://i.stack.imgur.com/AbzOL.png) i'm working with crystal report 13.0.7 in my report. i design crystal report:

```
group 1 : grab
group 2 :   car
detail  :       detail
group 1 : (blank space i want remove)
group 2 :   moto
detail  :       detail
group 1 :(blank space i want remove)
group 2 :   taxi
detail  :       detail
```

Edit
[this is report's design](https://i.stack.imgur.com/dopER.png) 
i want suppress the blank space in group 1 like description, but i can't find solution for that

Comment: provide the desing of your report too (not the preview one)
Since probably this space is coming from the group footer??

Comment: Reduce the Group Footers to the minimum size allowed, this will remove your blank space... since the blank space is not coming from group1 header

Comment: i mean i need to remove blank space section group header 1 in the second times(this time group 1 turn to blank) after it showing

Comment: Thanks you so much its works .

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As it is shown, it appears that the blank section you are talking about is coming from the Group Footer of the 2nd Group, not from group1 header.

Waht you have to do is reduce the Group Footers to the minimum size allowed, this will remove your blank space...